# How to design a layout that has two column per row

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would want so within one View wrapper to have always new row of two boxes.

Currently I have something like this which it works fine but If I am to populate dynamically then I have to write some if conditions.

```html
   <ScrollView>
        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <View style={{width:'50%',margin:4, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
                <Text>test</Text>
                <Text>test</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{width:'50%',margin:4, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
                <Text>test2</Text>
                <Text>test</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <View style={{width:'50%',margin:4, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
                <Text>test</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{width:'50%',margin:4, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
                <Text>test2</Text>
                <Text>test</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

Are there any way on how to solve this without conditioning, so just iterate thru a list and the two column boxes will automatically adjust!

Also Can I achieve this using Flatlist? I like the flatlist because it has the onEndReached action.

Comment: See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#numcolumns

Comment: thnx I think this is what I was looking!

Comment: u can add as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Adding flexDirection to a component's style determines the primary axis of its layout. Should the children be organized horizontally (row) or vertically (column)? The default is column.
you just add one view and give flexDirection:'col',

[Referency](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html)

```
<ScrollView>
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'col'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} >
    <Text>test</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}} >
    <Text>test</Text>
    </View>
  </View>

  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} >
      <Text>test</Text>
    </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'col'}} >
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'green'}} >
          <Text>test</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} >
          <Text>test</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
  </View>
</View>
</ScrollView>
```